# What the heck is Apple_Ubiquity_Message?

Tags: macos, operating-system, environment-variables, icloud, launchctl

OSX 10.8.4

```
> printenv
...
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-YzDhDA/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
...
> ls -al /tmp/launch-YzDhDA/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
srw-rw-rw-  1 user  wheel  0 Jul 25 10:01 /tmp/launch-YzDhDA/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
```

StackOverflow wants me to add some sentences with proper grammar. I tried to cat that file, but it does not emit anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's definitely iCloud related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's part of Apple's ubiquity system (more commonly known as iCloud). Programs that support iCloud can use it to communicate with the ubiquity daemon (`ubd`), and it's defined  in your environment so programs that use iCloud can find & use it.

More technically: the file /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ubd.plist tells your user instance of `launchd` to create that socket file, and then put a reference to it in the environment of all processes `launchd` creates under the name Apple_Ubiquity_Message. launchd doesn't actually start `ubd` until something connects to & uses that socket. I'm not particularly familiar with the iCloud APIs, but I don't think app developers access it directly; instead they use iCloud APIs and *those* use Apple_Ubiquity_Message behind the scenes.

Net result: you can ignore it, unless you're interested in the details of how iCloud works.

UPDATE: Apple apparently changed the way this works in Mavericks -- `ubd` is still there, but Apple_Ubiquity_Message (and the socket it pointed to) are not. I'm not sure what the new method to communicate with `ubd` is (maybe Mach messages?), but any program that uses the iCloud APIs should just continue to work.

Comment: Is this a must run service or can it be disabled? (If yes, how?) TIA.

Comment: @alphazero: It's needed for iCloud. You should be able to disable it with `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ubd.plist`, but (other than iCloud not working) I have no idea what the consequences might be -- everything might continue to operate fine, or everything might come to a crashing halt, or anything in between.

Comment: Thank you. I first noted the logs of this proc last night and given that I have not signed on to iCloud it was of some concern .. ;-)